# How to fix message spam from usbmuxd in console (_SendDetachNotification/_SendAttachNotification)

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, console

My console is flooded with messages like these:

```
11.01.12 21:21:39,819 com.apple.usbmuxd: _SendDetachNotification (thread 0x7fff7f6cb960): sending detach for device d0:23:db:3e:0b:82@fe80::d223:dbff:fe3e:b82._apple-mobdev._tcp.local.: _BrowseReplyReceivedCallback got bonjour removal.
11.01.12 21:21:46,596 com.apple.usbmuxd: _SendAttachNotification (thread 0x7fff7f6cb960): sending attach for device d0:23:db:3e:0b:82@fe80::d223:dbff:fe3e:b82._apple-mobdev._tcp.local.: _GetAddrInfoReplyReceivedCallback matched.
11.01.12 21:21:46,729 usbmuxd: _AMDeviceConnectByAddressAndPort (thread 0x100781000): IPv4
```

They always happen in this combination of three messages and around every 10-30seconds

Any suggestions where this is coming from and how to fix/disable it?

**Edit:** (additional Infos)
Ok it seems to be originating from my iPhone (MAC `d0:23:db:3e:0b:82`)...

There are no Wifi-Printers or anything like that in the Network.
And the Messages are still there when all USB Devices are disconnected.

**Edit2:**
This seems to be coming from iPhone Wifi-Sync, is there any way to get rid of this spam without diabling Wifi-Sync for the phone?

Comment: Do you have a USB or network printer attached to the machine?

Comment: No. And even if I unplug all USB devices this message is still showing up in the console.

Comment: OK. Do you have an iPhone? If so, can you look under Settings>General>About and tell me what your Wi-Fi Address is? Also, can you go open /Applications/Utilities/Network Utility.app, under the Info tab select your default connection method and tell me what the hardware address is? Also, do you have a wireless printer in the area?

Comment: It seems to be originated from the iPhone (the MAC in the message is the one used by the phone, nice call on that). My Airpot uses `00:1d:4f:ff:a2:5b` as it's MAC. There are no Wifi-Printers

Comment: Do you sync your iPhone over WIFI with iTunes?

Comment: Have you installed Xcode at any time? I had a similar problem which was related to Xcode.

Comment: @Mattlove yes i'm syncing over wifi but this also happens when itunes is not running

Comment: @Anthony yes i've got xcode - what did you do to solve that?

Comment: I had something similar, although it wasn't coming from my iPhone, it was coming from a broken install of Xcode (something to do with the interface with the iPhone simulator). I removed Xcode, then reinstalled. Hope this helps.

Comment: Getting hammered with frequent (loud!) warnings from VirusBarrier X6 related to USBMUXD activity. Stopped when I disabled the Wi-Fi/iPad option in iTunes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open Console and highlight the usbmuxd spam, then click [ignore sender] in the toolbar:

[image: usbmuxd]

To re-enable usbmuxd spam, click the [^] symbol in the lower bottom left corner then (x):

[image: usbmuxd]

---

This will allow you to safely ignore **any** Console spam you would like without actually disabling anything other than the message that you see in Console.

Comment: This isn't a perfect solution as it may disable some relevant bug messages from usbmuxd too but it's probably the best solution at the moment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and quitting duet (the app to use the iPhone as a Mac display) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can always edit your `/etc/syslog.conf` file to send messages from usbmuxd to their own private log file. If you never want to see them, send it to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

What is also interesting is that this is last entry I see in the console before my Mac hangs (well it's the last entry I see before the reboot messages). Could be a coincidence, of course, because there are so many of these messages. I've tried disabling usbmuxd to see if it is relating to the hanging problem.

I moved /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.usbmuxd.plist to ~/Documents and restarted. You can move it back and restart to get it running again.

Comment: same for me.  i am getting lots of crashes and time when my mini wont wake up.  This is always the last thing in the logs.  Did disabling it stop the crashing?  i just turned off wifi sync for my iPhone, we'll see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The _apple-mobdev._tcp.local. is an mDNS message (aka bonjour) and is being broadcast on your network from an iPhone.

You can see it being broadcast on your network by running:

```
dns-sd -B _apple-mobdev
```

on any Mac. It is the iPhone advertising it can be attached to.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with the way OS X / iTunes handles the wifi sync to the 4S.
Connect it by cable and drag a few songs to it, let it sync via wire, and the console messages should disappear after that..

Hope its fixed in a software update.

Answer (score 0):

These messages disappear when you disable wifi sync for your iDevices. This is really annoying me, too, because I like wifi sync, but the log becomes useless with all the usbmuxd spam.

Comment: Yep this is the problem, is just don't know how to get rid of the spam without disabling wifi sync...