# How to fix "com.apple.dock.extra: ... Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication" in system.log

Tags: dock, user-account

On a recently installed (from internet via Recovery Disk) 10.7.4 Lion system the system.log is filled with multiple "`com.apple.dock.extra: ... Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication`" message.

Have tried creating a new account, with only 2 icons in Dock: Finder and Recycle bin, though that also generates these "`com.apple.dock.extra: ... Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication`" messages in system.log.

System.log excerpt:

```
Jun 24 16:14:50 mac03 com.apple.launchctl.Aqua[1209]: usage: launchctl load [-wF] [-D <user|local|network|system|all>] paths...
Jun 24 16:14:50 mac03 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[1051] (com.apple.launchctl.Aqua[1209]): Exited with code: 1
Jun 24 16:14:52 mac03 com.apple.dock.extra[1231]: Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication
Jun 24 16:14:52: --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Jun 24 16:14:52 mac03 com.apple.dock.extra[1231]: 2012-06-24 16:14:52.250 com.apple.dock.extra[1231:1507] Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication
Jun 24 16:14:52 mac03 com.apple.dock.extra[1231]: 2012-06-24 16:14:52.303 com.apple.dock.extra[1231:1507] Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication
Jun 24 16:14:52 mac03 com.apple.dock.extra[1231]: 2012-06-24 16:14:52.304 com.apple.dock.extra[1231:1507] Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication
Jun 24 16:14:52 mac03 com.apple.dock.extra[1231]: 2012-06-24 16:14:52.305 com.apple.dock.extra[1231:1507] Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication
```

How can this behavior be "fixed"? The goal is to prevent these messages from appearing in system.log.

Comment: I get these as well, don't think they are a reason to worry.

Comment: I don't worry, but would like to get rid of these messages.

Answer (score 1):

You have a similar request to this question:

[How to fix message spam from usbmuxd in console (_SendDetachNotification/_SendAttachNotification)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36339/how-to-fix-message-spam-from-usbmuxd-in-console-senddetachnotification-sendat)

The answer I put there should work if this hasn't fixed itself via time or an upgrade to a newer OS. Just send the com.apple.dock.extra messages to /dev/null by editing `/etc/syslog.conf`